# Font Awesome - Wordpress - Icon displaying with a box

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am just pasted Font Awesome into the head of my WP themes header.php

And I know the fonts are working, but in the HTML I think I have made a mistake and I just cannot see what!!

http://goo.gl/Yoit33 - there is row of rounded boxes, 2nd row down, second in from the right.

any help I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the classes `.fa` and `.fa-wheelchair` from the `a` tag as the icon is actually being loaded in through the `i` tag.

From this:

```
<a href="http://www.synaxishosting.co.uk/test/mob/vat-exemption/" class="fa fa-wheelchair icon-5x btn rounded">
    <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
</a>
```

To This:

```
<a href="http://www.synaxishosting.co.uk/test/mob/vat-exemption/" class="icon-5x btn rounded">
    <i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i>
</a>
```